# Detecting integers that are norms of algebraic integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K / \mathbb{Q}$ be a number field and $\mathfrak{a}$ an integral ideal of $K$ of norm $n$. I am trying to get a better understanding of how the ideal class group and narrow ideal class group can be used to detect integers in $\mathbb{Z}$ that can be written as norms of algebraic integers of $K$.

**Question 1** Am I understanding correctly that if $\mathfrak{a}$ is in the principal class of the ideal class group then either $n$ or $-n$ can be represented as the norm of an algebraic integer of $K$ ?

**Question 2** Let's suppose now that $\mathfrak{a}$ lies in the principal class of the narrow ideal class group. Am I correct in my understanding that then $n$ is the norm of an algebraic integer of $K$ ? More importantly for me : is this an if and only if ? I am slightly confused about the impact of the the requirement that every positive embedding is positive.

Comment: Yes to both. (1) $\mathfrak{a} = (a)$, so $N(\mathfrak{a}) = n = |N(a)|$. (2) $\mathfrak{a} = (a)$, where $a$  is totally positive, so $N(a)>0$, but this is not an if and only if, $a$ can have even number of real embeddings in which $a$ is negative.

Comment: Thanks! To correct the if and only if would be it be enough to say that the reduction of $\mathfrak{a}$ belongs to a certain subset of the narrow ideal classes?